# From audio PCM 16 bit to 8 bit - getting noise

Tags: java, android, audio, pcm

I implemented the following algorithm to convert PCM 16 bit audio data to 8 bit:

```
if(encoding == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT){
    int len = data.length;          
    data1 = new byte[len/2];
    int tempint;

    for (int k = 0, i=1; i < len; i+=2, k++) {
        tempint = ((int)data[i]) ^ 0x00000080; 
        data1[k] = (byte)tempint;
    }
    data=null;
}
```

where `data is byte[]`. After running this code, the output `contains a lot of noise` and suggest me that I'm doing something wrong here. `What should I do besides dropping the lower byte?`

[EDIT]: modified the code:

```
if(encoding == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT){

            int len = data.length;          
            data1 = new byte[len/2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {                   
                    data1[i] = data[i*2+1];     
            }

  }
```

`the input/output looks like:`

```
 Original data(counter:0) = 4
    Original data(counter:1) = -1
    Original data(counter:2) = 75
    Original data(counter:3) = -1
    Original data(counter:4) = 16
    Original data(counter:5) = -1
    Original data(counter:6) = 44
    Original data(counter:7) = -1
    Original data(counter:8) = 7
    Original data(counter:9) = -1
    Original data(counter:10) = 22
    Original data(counter:11) = -1
    Original data(counter:12) = 22
    Original data(counter:13) = -1
    Original data(counter:14) = 12
    Original data(counter:15) = -1

Output data:(counter:0) = -1
Output data:(counter:1) = -1
Output data:(counter:2) = -1
Output data:(counter:3) = -1
Output data:(counter:4) = -1
Output data:(counter:5) = -1
Output data:(counter:6) = -1
Output data:(counter:7) = -1
Output data:(counter:8) = -1
Output data:(counter:9) = -1
Output data:(counter:10) = -1
Output data:(counter:11) = -1
Output data:(counter:12) = -1
Output data:(counter:13) = -1
Output data:(counter:14) = -1
Output data:(counter:15) = -1
```

It does not matter if I drop first or second byte, the noise still remain. Here I dropped first byte(instead of second)

Comment: Consider looking at the other byte of the two bytes the 16 bit occupy.

Comment: Are you suggesting: for (int k = 0, `i=0`; i < len; i+=2, k++)? Dropping byte 0,2,4,6,etc instead of 1,3,5,7,etc?

Comment: You could build a cryptographic RNG using the noise as entropy input.  :)

Comment: Why do you think I should do that:) ?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - you think I should convert each 2 consecutive bytes to short, then apply some operation (>> 8) to each short, convert back to byte[] and then drop the lower byte?

Comment: @AlexandruCircus - basically, but first you have to figure out the endianness of the source data - is the first byte of each pair the high order or the low order?  Also, an equivalent operation would be to just grab the high byte and ignore the low byte, as in either case you are truncating.  If you wish to round instead of truncate, only then would you need to look at the lower byte.

Comment: You shouldn't do anything besides dropping the lower byte unless you want to get into dither. The main problem here is XOR'ing with 0x80. That's nonsense.

Comment: The xor suggests a conversion between a signed and an offset zero unsigned format, but it's not clear that would be appropriate.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - thanks for pointing out the rounding option - the data is in LE format, so I dropped out each first byte of each sample, but the audio sounds like an old walkie-talkie :(. I want to round, but don't know how..

Comment: Rounding is probably not going to make that much difference, .  If you could post the original and output somewhere it may be possible to offer more hints.  Also you might want to play with a program called audacity.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - added the edit you suggested

Comment: It looks like you signal might be very weak, but you can't post enough of it as text to know for sure.  Please either examine/normalize it in audacity, or put a snippet of the file online somewhere.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - http://www.fileshare.ro/e29673597 - here I uploaded a demo (the output of conversion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following algorithm has considerably reduced the amount of noise, but can't get rid of it completely:

```
if(encoding == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT){  
            ShortBuffer intBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
            short[] samples16Bit = new short[intBuf.remaining()];
            intBuf.get(samples16Bit);
            data1 = new byte[samples16Bit.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < samples16Bit.length; i++) {
                data1[i] = (byte)((samples16Bit[i] / 256)+128);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The noise that you are experiencing is simply caused by the bitrange that you have converted your audio to. The noise floor for 16Bit signals is -96dB yet the noise floor for 8Bit signals is -48dB. This may not seem like much in terms of these numbers but it is a huge difference. Downsampling algorithms almost always employ some kind of dithering to reduce the amount of noise associated with the conversion. You can demonstrate the differences in quality (and noise level) quite easily by creating a sine wave in 8Bit programmatically or with any decent audio program and just listening to the result. You will find that 8Bit is not really quality. Repeat the experiment with a 16Bit sine wave to compare. It's not you, it's the bitrange.

Comment: Yes, there are unavoidable limitations.  But the quality will depend a lot on the dynamic range of the original.  If it has a fairly strong signal the result shouldn't be too horrid, but if it's relatively weak to begin with such that you leave several of the bits effectively unused, its going to be bad.  More importantly, it is **premature** to declare that this is the source of the problem, especially when the posted code seems to be wrong endian and doing a probably mistaken conversion to unsigned.

Comment: I agree that is a bit premature but it's always best to know what the actual limits of the system actually are. If you know what 8 Bits sounds like natively without conversion, then you at least have a reference point to go from for a conversion attempt.

Comment: "Bit conversion algorithms almost always employ some kind of filtering to reduce the amount of noise associated with the conversion." Not correct. Bit reduction algorithms should implement dithering, but not filtering.

Comment: Correct, it's dithering not filtering. Updated response.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
int len = data.length;          
data1 = new byte[len/2];
for (int i=0; i < len/2; ++i)
    data1[i] = data[i*2];
```

I'm assuming your data is bigendian. If it's LE, this should work:

```
int len = data.length;          
data1 = new byte[len/2];
for (int i=0; i < len/2; ++i)
    data1[i] = data[i*2+1];
```

Comment: You might find this helpful, as well. It's not my best writing, but there it is: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013/05/the-abcs-of-pcm-uncompressed-digital.html

Comment: Thanks @Bjorn Roche for your answer and your blog. I tried the above but the noise still remains... My data is LE, so I drop the first byte of each sample, as per your example above, but still getting noise. I think I should convert each sample to short, apply some transformation on each sample(short), revert back to byte and THEN drop the lower byte of each sample. Some lower-pass-filter I guess. I'm still digging for this :).

Comment: Don't filter, that's only appropriate for samplerate conversions, not bitdepth conversions. @ronnied has a point about the noisefloor, and looking at the data you posted I agree that your signal is very weak, meaning that the relative noise floor is high.

Comment: If this is for a WAV file, note that 8-bit WAV files use unsigned data, and the above conversion gives you signed, so you'll have to do that conversion as well.

Comment: @BjornRoche - interesting, I believe the code *is* doing a signed to offset-unsigned conversion with the XOR

Comment: The correct conversion from signed to unsigned is addition, because you are effectively moving the zero point. IIRC, I think you need to add 128 in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You have a lot of noise for multiple reasons. <s>You are firstly only filling every other value of the array, the values you are not filling are automatically zero, that distorts the waveform hugely.</s> Secondly you are just picking the first 8 bits of the original data, this means you lose all of the information on a specific datapoint if the first 8 bits of the datapoint happen to be all zeros, the information may be in the higher bits.

A naive suggestion would be to scale all of the datapoints (divide by 2^7 if signed) so that the highest datapoint is at most 8 bit, you will still lose information and introduce distortion because you are forced to save the data in integers and integer division will force   values in the same (close) range to be equal after division but this should be a lot less noisy :)

Thanks to the comment below, if you are only taking every other datapoint from the original you will introduce a distortion known as [Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't he filling each spot in the array but skipping every second value from the source array?

Comment: Let me understand: PCM 16 bit suggests that each sample is composed by 2 consecutive bytes. I want to transform to 8 bit, reduce sample to be stored in only 1 byte. The first step would be to create a short[] from the byte[] (new short[dataByteArr.lenght/2]), apply some transformations(shorts[i] >>8 maybe?) to each short, then cast it to byte arr again. Is that right? If it is right, what kind of transforms should I apply?

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is just not based on a clear understanding of the subject matter.

Comment: It has been long since I had signal-processing, I would love to know what I was wrong about.

Comment: Beyond the mistake you lined out, the loss of dynamic range when going to 8 bit linear samples is unavoidable (though normalizing the amplitude first could help, or for some types of sound, using an 8 bit log rather than linear format)   The code does not take every other datapoint, but rather should take every other byte, which is to say just the high byte from each data point.